# JPA - Error trying to map a shared composite key using IdClass instead of an EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa, orm, mapping, eclipselink

Once you see the Composite Keys and the Entities that use them which I post down in the code block, please refer to the next pseudotable that I need to have in the database for the *Address* entity:

Address Table:

```
ADDRESS
-------------------------------
DOCUMENTTYPE    INT2         PK
DOCUMENTNR      VARCHAR(10)  PK
ALIAS           VARCHAR(20)  PK
FULLADDRESS     VARCHAR(100)
...
```

Entities & Composite Keys:

```
@Embeddable
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private DocumentType  documentType;
    private String        documentNr;
    ...

@Entity
@IdClass(Document.class)
public class Person {
    @Id
    private DocumentType  documentType;
    @Id
    private String        documentNr;
    private String        fullName;
    ...

@Embeddable
public class AddressId implements Serializable {
    private DocumentType  documentType;
    private String        documentNr;
    private String        alias;
    ...

@Entity
@IdClass(AddressId.class)
public class Address {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Person        person;
    @Id
    private String        alias;
    private String        fullAddress;
    ...
```

**NOTE:** *DocumentType* is an *enum*.

Well, I am trying to have that mapping for the *Address* entity but it doesn't work, I don't know why. It keeps saying (EclipseLink) that I have the problem that the names and types don't match. I don't understand why if the *AddressId* IdClass doesn't have the alias attribute (and of course neither the *Address* entity) then it works like a charm, as well as with the full *AddressId* IdClass (with the alias attribute) but using EmbeddedId. What I need is to have the *Address* entity just like I posted.

Where is the mapping error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add [`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html) to your `enum` field

Like this:

```
@Id
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocumentType  documentType;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is not that because enum types are implicitly persisted with the ORDINAL assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly. However, here is an observation that may help:

I think your database schema needs work before you map it to Java. Here are some suggestions:

1: Each and every database table should have one and only one primary key (typically of type long) and the primary key should have no business meaning. No composite keys anywhere. Since there are no composite keys, your original problem is no longer an issue.

2:The primary key is typically named after the table name with ID after it (never use just 'ID' as the name).

Example:
 Address
 addressID long primaryKey

3: The other fields that you call primary keys should probably be foreign keys (type long with ID after them) referencing other table's primary keys.

4: You need to properly normalize your database tables. Example: the column 'fullAddress' probably should be broken up into streetAddress, city, stateID, countryID, zipcode. Another example: ADDRESS table should contain only address information. Why does it have DOCUMENTTYPE? What does that have to do with addresses?

5: The names of your database tables and columns should be clearly understood. The column 'DOCUMENTNR' doesn't mean anything to me.

6:Your database tables and columns should be nowns, and they typically should be mapped to java classes with the same name. Instead, you have a class called AddressId that apparently maps to Address database table. Rename the class to Address.

7: you need to decide what columns are unique and not nullable.

You can contact your friendly neighborhood Database Admin for help creating your database schema.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not what I'm looking for. Those things that you recommend I appreciate but it doesn't answer my question (as you state at the beginning). This problem I post it's just a mapping problem for JPA, for a Database that already exists and I can't change, that database is well normalized and those composites Id are unique and it is required to be like that, the schema is good, I just need to map it to JPA. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The derived id for address must incorporate the id from person, which is document not its components.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/mappedbyid shows some examples but is aimed more at embeddables, but the concept is the same for idclasses.  Try

```
public class AddressId implements Serializable {
    private Document person;
    private String   alias;
```